# Page doesn't redirect when pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, if-statement, enter, form-fields

So I have a text field where the user has to type a password to be able to download a PDF file. If the password is correct it redirects the user to the PDF file url if the pass is wrong it redirects the user to another page called incorrect (incorrect.html).

Everything works fine. The only problem is when you press the Enter key it doesn't redirect the page. It only works when you click on the Submit button.

Is there a way to fix this?

Many thanks!

**Input Text Field And Submit Button**

```
<form name="login">
<input class="gen-label" type="text" name="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;">
<input class="button submit" type="button" value="Submit"  onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function TheLogin() {
var password = 'Pass1';
if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="file_to_download.pdf";
}
else {
  location.href="incorrect.html";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `<input type="submit"` instead of a button.

Comment: This is not very secure at all.  You are storing the password in plain text in the source?  You should have the form post to a server-side script, such as a PHP file or similar, compare the password there and have the script perform a server side redirection to the document if the password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="submit"` Triggers the form submit on enter, button won't.

Another thing is change the else code to shown below for redirection.

```
<input class="gen-label" type="text" name="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;">
<input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Submit"  onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form><script>
function TheLogin() {
var password = 'Pass1';
if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="file_to_download.pdf";
}
else {
  window.location="incorrect.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tested it but it didn't work. I've just noticed something: When you type anything let's say 12345 the url changes to url_path.html?pass=12345

Comment: this means the form is submitted. The form parameters get appended at the end of url in case of get method. To avoid this, use method=POST inside form tag.

Comment: Sorry could you show me exactly where should I type method=POST. I'm a bit lost

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Shall I show you the actual website?

Comment: Well, when I click Submit or when I press Enter nothing happens. It only changes the url to whatever pass I type

Comment: did you changed the script to ><script>
function TheLogin() {
var password = 'Pass1';
if (this.document.login.pass.value == password) {
  top.location.href="file_to_download.pdf";
}
else {
  window.location="incorrect.html";
  }
}</script>

Comment: Make sure you have incorrect.html at correct place otherwise it will respond with 404 error

Comment: Yup I double checked and everything's in the right place

Comment: It doesn't when you press the Enter key. The demo example has my original code. I've tested it with yours and it didn't work.

Comment: in form add onsubmit="TheLogin(this.form)"